# How to parse a multi dimensional array between php pages?

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, output

I have created an `array` in `array.php` and would like to use it another file `index.php` How can I do this?

This is my array:

```
$fruits[]=array(
    "$int"=>array(
        'a' => $apple,
        'b' => $banana,
        'c' => $citrus
    )
);
```

Comment: what does "pass it into index.php" mean? are you `require`ing index.php at the end of that file? -1 as it's not clear.

Comment: what is "reached the end"

Comment: have you tried something? adding it to session and accessing it in index.php?

Comment: I guess that is just a big gap of knowledge. What do you want do - what is your final goal? Maybe we know a better way than `passing this array from one php document to another`.

Comment: or if it is just a simple include, the variable will be available automatically to index.php

Comment: @user3506938 Could you please explain the what is reached and end

Comment: it should be a simple incude, but the how would i print out this array to check it has worked?

Comment: To print the whole array .. use `print_r($fruits);` as I showed you on my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You have multiple ways to do that...

- Using http_build_query (Recommended way)
- Using sessions.
- Using serialization / deserialization
- Using json_encoding / json_decoding.

and a lot *other* ways...

#### Demonstration using the second way..

**`array.php`**

```
<?php
//.. your code..
$arr = array(1,2,3);
header("location:index.php?value=".serialize($arr));
```

**`index.php`**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['value']))
{
 $arr = unserialize($_GET['value']);
 print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: it prints -  Array ( )  - not the values

Comment: Did you really try the above code ? It will print all the elements in the array together. If you want them individually you need to use `echo`

Comment: why are you inventing a new way to pass a get argument instead of just  [using get arguments as designed](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)? There should be no `unserialize` step.

Comment: @AD7six, Can't you see I have put _and a lot other ways..._ on my answer ?

Comment: The `header()` is for redirection to your index.php and if you output anything before that will throw a notice. By the way why do you want to do an `include()` after the header ? I really don't have an idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: _Mentioning many ways but missing the most obvious_ .. @AD7six, I agree to that point , But I don't agree with _I can see that the only way you propose/demonstrate passing the variable in the url - is using serialize._ because I never ever mentioned the word _only_ anywhere.

Comment: @AD7six, Come on its impossible to list all the examples, OP can read it from the manual right ? **The main point of the example is an array cannot be sent as it is through querystring, it needs to be represented in a string..** I don't see any wrong in this. Also, since you mentioned about `http_build_query` I had mentioned that too and put up a _recommended way_ next to that.

Comment: Feel free to canibalize [this deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238449/how-to-parse-array-through-a-php-header-location/23238629#23238629). The main problems with this answer are: 1) He's not redirecting at all 2) the only code example is weird. You don't need to mention all the examples, only present  _a_ example that a novice user can use and understand. Saying "you can do x or <here's some wat?? code you can copy and paste>" doesn't help IMO. Anyway - I'm done.

Comment: @AD7six, I really don't have an idea why you deleted that answer. I think it should stay, nicely explained.

Comment: thank you ! it works now, sorry for having an unclear question, but your answer helped !  :)

Comment: @AD7six, That one really need moar upvotes. Well I shall compensate you in other way ;)

Comment: Is their a way of doing this usin post? or making sure the array is not displayed in the url?

Comment: Sure, you can use `cURL` to do that. There are lot of examples available.. Try with your attempts on a new question and we are glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Sessions work the best for this, it doesn't add the variable in the URL either.

Basically all you have to do is call

```
session_start();
```

at the top of each php page (before anything is outputted to the browser) where you want to have access to the session variables. You can then set/retrieve a variable using

```
// set
$_SESSION['varname'] = "something";
// retrieve
$somevar = $_SESSION['varname'];
```

This method allows you to use the variable on several pages too.

Comment: Didn't you see this was already suggested on the second point of my answer under _mulitple ways_? Its really pity in wasting my time on writing such detailed answers. No matter how a answer was written in detail people just don't read it.

Comment: I read your answer and used it, the serialization / deserialization one. However then I needed to use the array in several php pages and decided to investigate more into the sessions you suggested. So I thought I should put down an example of session use.

You have helped ! :)

Answer (score 0):

`include("array.php");` at the position of `index.php` where you need the array although your question does not clearly state what you are really trying to achieve here.

Comment: How can I then print this variable? Ive used echo "array - " . $array[fruit]["b"];

Comment: oh sorry, $fruits[0]["b"]; ?

Comment: That should be correct but I don't understand why you are asking. Just try it and see if it works ;-)